# What does "Create the archive" mean

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.sothis.tech/en/detecting-intruders-at-home-ii/ however I am stuck on point 5

Enable the network card’s promiscuous mode during computer start-up. Create the archive “/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0” and enter the following values:
[image]

I don't know what is meant by "create the archive" I am using a raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: I guess it's a typo - just create the _file_. But doesn't todays rpi use systemd-networkd?

Comment: @KamilCuk How would I go about doing that. I have only used the desktop version of raspbian, so I'm new to CLI

Comment: `vim` and `nano` are common command line file editors. But for people not accustomed to `vim` nor `nano` I recommend using the file editor from `mc` midnight commander - the whole `mc` interface is very simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a file named: `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` and add the lines you show in the image.

Comment: O the file should be a text file yeah

Comment: Idea O surely /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0 is the filepath and not the file name?

Comment: @LyraOrwell path and name, name is `eth0` and the path is whatever before that, but you don't need to care, something like `mc /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` will likely do the right thing.